# ISS Live Views of Earth on Nasa's EHDC Camera appear to be retrograde orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss

If the Orbit of the ISS is Prograde and Synchronized with the same orbit as the Earth, would not the Live EHDC views motion appear Stationary?

Answer (score 6):

The orbit of the ISS is not synchronized with Earth's rotation. It orbits Earth approximately once every 90 minutes. We would not expect the view of an earth facing camera to be stationary

Comment: Thank You for your response.